# Database table not found cakephp

Tags: mysql, model, controller, cakephp-1.3

I am new to `cakephp`, though I have worked in `codeigniter` hence having `MVC` knowledge. So my controller `posts_controller.php` is:

```
<?php
class PostsController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');



    public function index() {
         $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
    }
}
```

Model `Post.php` is :

```
<?php
class Post extends AppModel {

}
```

I have created a table `posts` in my database and added some data. But when I run my controoler `http://localhost/cake1.3/index.php/posts` it says

> Missing Database Table
>
> Error: Database table posts for model Post was not found.
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\views\errors\missing_table.ctp

Whats wrong with the code ?

NB: I needed to use `cakephp version 1.3`

Comment: You could try to load the model manualy.. `$this->loadModel('Post');` To see if it works.. else there is something wrong with the conection to the database.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Database table posts for model Post was not found.

This error indicates that there is no 'posts' table in your database.

A couple solutions:

- check your database connection App->config->database.php and make sure that is all correct.
- ensure that you have a table in your database called 'posts'